# Add / Remove Post Type from "Link to existing content" popup

Tags: custom-post-types, links, wysiwyg

I would like to be able to remove a custom post type AND add attached media (PDF's, Images, Docs, etc) to the "Link to existing content" in the Add / Edit link popup in the WYSIWYG editor.

Essentially, I've created a custom content type, but have way to many with the same name.  So, I'd like those removed from the search results.

In addition, I have a bunch of PDF's I've uploaded and would like to easily be able to link to those.

Anyone ever accomplished this, know a plugin or have the hook to modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question but I found an answer at [Here](http://hampelgroup.com/how-to-hide-custom-post-types-from-the-link-to-existing-content-list/) by [Simon Hampel](http://hampelgroup.com/author/simon/) at the bottom. Cool filter, but I coulnd't find a whole lot of documentation on it so I'm not 100% sure everything it's connected to. One thing I do know is it's used to pull the links on 'Link to existing content'. Put this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_wp_link_query_args($query)
{
    $pt_new = array();

    $exclude_types = array('exclude_post_types_here');

    foreach ($query['post_type'] as $pt)
    {
        if (in_array($pt, $exclude_types)) continue;
        $pt_new[] = $pt;
    }

    $query['post_type'] = $pt_new;

    return $query;
}
add_filter('wp_link_query_args', 'custom_wp_link_query_args');
```